# FFMPEG how to edit the existing code to get video scaled and then overlay an image?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, watermark

I'm using a website script that has been created by someone who unfortunately doesn't provide any help on this subject.

Here is the piece of code:

$com=$global_settings["ffmpeg_path"]." -i \"".$apath."\" -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -t ".$duration." -vf 'movie=".$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].site_root."/content/watermark-video.png [wm];[in][wm] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2 [out]' -vf scale=498:-1 ".$flv_path;

It's supposed to do what I need which is described in title of this post, but it doesn't. It scales video, but doesn't apply a png watermark. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you distill that down to the actual command sent to FFMPEG? I.e. take out all your PHP (or whatever language) markings and resolve all the variable names to real values? That'll make it easier to debug.

Comment: The code you posted will be resolved to a single string, stored in $com. What is the value of $com after you run the code? It will be something like `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 <other options> -o output.mp4`.

Comment: Already answered at https://superuser.com/q/1273944/114058.